# How to retrieve all transactions from a public address?

Tags: bitcoind

I run a Bitcoin node with `txindex=1` so I can retrieve any transaction from the txId.
My question: if I have any public address, how can I retrieve all transactions involving this address (inputs and outputs) with the Bitcoin Core commands ?

Comment: Something like this:
https://blockchain.info/fr/address/19HuaNprtc8MpG6bmiPoZigjaEu9xccxps

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Bitcoin Core does not index transaction based on address.

If you want to do this, you'll either need an indexing tool/service, or implement the P2P protocol yourself to be notified of all transactions.